# How to prove that $(1+\cos a)/(\sin a)=(\sin a)/(1-\cos a)$?

Tags: trigonometry

How can I prove this relation $(1+\cos a)/(\sin a)=(\sin a)/(1-\cos a)$ ?

I tried to start from relation $\cos^2a+\sin^2a=1$ but relation went crazy with lot of $\cos$ and $\sin$ and $\sin^2$.

Comment: Note that $(1+x)(1-x)  = 1-x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: multiply by the denominators and rearrange

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{1+\cos a}{\sin a} & = \dfrac{(1+\cos a)\cdot(1-\cos a)}{\sin a(1-\cos a)}\\ \, \\
&=\dfrac{1-\cos^2a}{\sin a(1-\cos a)}\quad\text{since: $(a+b)\cdot(a-b)=a^2-b^2$}\\\,\\
&=\dfrac{\cos^2a+\sin^2a-\cos^2a}{\sin a(1-\cos a)}\quad\text{since: $\cos^2a+\sin^2a=1$}\\\,\\
&=\dfrac{\sin^2a}{\sin a(1-\cos a)}\\\,\\&=\dfrac{\sin a\cdot\sin a}{\sin a(1-\cos a)}\\\,\\
&=\boxed{\dfrac{\sin a}{1-\cos a}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{d}{c}\Rightarrow ad=bc$. Then, you can use the relation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try cross-multiplying and then $(1+\cos(a))\cdot(1-\cos(a)) = 1 - \cos^2(a) = \sin^2(a)$.